# Apache VirtualHost Server Domain Not Accessible With SSL On Local Devices?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, nat

I am configuring a web server with:

Apache2
DDclient
UFW
Letsencrypt.com certification (SSL)

My issue is that the domain is only partly accessible? Everything works as it should, but when I try to access the domain from my phone (using 4G) **and** from my laptop (WIFI), the phone connection times out (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT), and my laptop gets a blocked GET-request.

I can access the site perfectly through ethernet, though I suspect it is not a true connection that passes the request through my router - and my friends are able to visit the domain through an actual internet connection with my router. But why my phone connection doesn't work fumbles me.

Following are my VirtualHost settings, Router settings and UFW settings:

**VirtualHost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias www.website.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Redirect permanent / https://website.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias www.website.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/as
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Router Settings**

1. HTTPS   192.168.0.103    **External Port** 443    **Internal Port**
   80
2. HTTP    192.168.0.103    **External Port** 80    **Internal Port**
   80

**UFW**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Like, everything seems correct but somehow either the firewall is blocking certain entries; the website gets overloaded; or some settings are messed up. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualhost is wrongly configured. You dont need the *:80 configuration for it to work. If you set your external port to 443 apache will skip directly to the HTTPS domain.